# SSIS: Unfamiler SSIS Exception Message "There were build errors. Would you like to coninue and run last successful build?"

Tags: exception, ssis

I am building SSIS packages on the dev server.  I am getting the following message:  "There were build errors.  Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

The only time I have ever received a message like this is when I've had syntax errors in C#, VB, .NET...etc.  I have NEVER seen a message like this in SSIS.  There are no validation errors and I am completely perplexed on why this is happening....any thoughts?  I would like to rectify this so I can go home for the day.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my machine and error went away.  Still weird though, I haven't ever seen this exception using SSIS.